# Insert zeros in a dataframe based on value on other in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have in R two big data.frames that look like

```
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
5 5 5 5 4 4 5 5 1 1
```

and

```
0.98 0.97 0.99 0.98 0.99 0.97 0.96 0.89 0.90 0.99
0.99 0.97 0.99 0.98 0.99 0.97 0.97 0.89 0.90 0.98
0.79 0.97 0.99 0.98 0.99 0.97 0.96 0.89 0.90 0.99
0.89 0.98 0.99 0.98 0.99 0.97 0.96 0.89 0.91 0.91
```

Both datasets have the same dimensions. Basically, I would like to have a 0 in the second data.frame if there is a 5 in the first, so it would look like:

```
0.98 0.97 0.99 0.98 0.99 0.97 0.96 0.89 0.90 0.99
0.99 0.97 0.99 0.98 0.99 0.97 0.97 0.89 0.90 0.98
0.79 0.97 0.99 0.98 0.99 0.97 0.96 0.89 0.90 0.99
0    0    0    0    0.99 0.97 0    0    0.91 0.91
```

But i can not do it column by column because I have almost 50000 columns. I tried with ifelse but I couldn´t do it. Some idea??

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is surprisingly easy:

```
df2[df1==5] <- 0
df2
    V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9  V10
1 0.98 0.97 0.99 0.98 0.99 0.97 0.96 0.89 0.90 0.99
2 0.99 0.97 0.99 0.98 0.99 0.97 0.97 0.89 0.90 0.98
3 0.79 0.97 0.99 0.98 0.99 0.97 0.96 0.89 0.90 0.99
4 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.99 0.97 0.00 0.00 0.91 0.91
```

It works because `df1==5` results in a logical matrix which can be used to subset `df2`:

```
df1==5
        V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L), V2 = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L), 
        V3 = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L), V4 = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 5L), V5 = c(1L, 
        3L, 1L, 4L), V6 = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L), V7 = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 5L
        ), V8 = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 5L), V9 = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), V10 = c(2L, 
        3L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(V1 = c(0.98, 0.99, 0.79, 0), V2 = c(0.97, 0.97, 
    0.97, 0), V3 = c(0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0), V4 = c(0.98, 0.98, 0.98, 
    0), V5 = c(0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99), V6 = c(0.97, 0.97, 0.97, 
    0.97), V7 = c(0.96, 0.97, 0.96, 0), V8 = c(0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 
    0), V9 = c(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.91), V10 = c(0.99, 0.98, 0.99, 0.91
    )), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, yes, in fact, they have the same dimensions. I spent hours because I did not imagine that this had such an easy solution! Thanks!